# Creating new collections vs array properties

Tags: mongodb

Coming from a MySQL background, I've been questioning the some of the design patterns when working with Mongo.  One question I keep asking myself is when should I create a new collection vs creating a property of an array type?  My current situation goes as follows:

- I have a collection of Users who all have at least 1 Inbox
- Each inbox has 0 or more messages
- Each message can have 0 or comments

My current structure looks like this:

```
{
username:"danramosd",
inboxes:[
    {
        name:"inbox1",
        messages:[
            {
                message:"this is my message"
                comments:[
                    {
                        comment:"this is a great message"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
]
}
```

For simplicity I only listed 1 inbox, 1 message and 1 comment.  Realistically though there could be many more.

An approach I believe that would work better is to use 4 collections:

- Users - stores just the username
- Inboxes - name of the inbox, along with the UID of User it belongs to
- Messages - content of the message, along with the UID of inbox it belongs to
- Comments - content of the comment, along with the UID of the message it belongs to.

So which one would be the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can help you with this question, because it is highly dependent on your application:

- how many inboxes/messages/comments do you have on average
- how often do you write/modify/delete these elements
- how often do you read them
- a lot of other things that I forgot to mention

When you are selecting one approach over another you are doing tradeofs.

If you store everything together (in one collection as your first case) you make it super easy to get all the things for a particular user. Taking apart the thing that most probably you do not need all the information at once, you at the same time makes it super hard to update some parts of the elements (try to write a query that will add a comment or remove the third comment). Even if this is easy - mongodb [does not handle well growing documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9306815/1090562) because whenever you exceeds the [padding factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/) it moves the document to another location (which is expensive) and increases the padding factor. Also keep in mind that this potentially can hit mongodb's [limit on the size of the document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size).

It is always a good idea to read all mongodb use cases before trying to design any storage schema. Not surprisingly they have a comprehensive [overview of your case](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/) as well.