# MongoDB - How to search array of dictionary in dictionary

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have Location table as below. I need to fetch the details of only driver whose ratings are above three for that particular location.

Thanks in advance...

```
[
    {
        "name":"Delhi",
        "cab_details(sub table)":[
            {
                "driver_details"(join):{
                    "name":"1111",
                    "ratings_above_three":true

                },
                "date_joining": date
            },
            {
                "driver_details":{
                    "name":"2222",
                    "ratings_above_three":false
                },
                "date_joining": date
            }                   
        ]
    }    
]
```

Comment: Did you try: db.collection.find({'cab_details.driver_details.ratings_above_three':true})

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you put your `drivers` into separate `collection`.
MongoDB does not handle very well growing objects.

Follow in your schema design  [the principle of least cardinality](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

Refer to this question: [mongodb-performance-with-growing-data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306815/mongodb-performance-with-growing-data-structure)

I suspect the model you presented is `City` from collection `cities`. So I would recommend creating a separate collection called `cab_drivers`, and populating it with `CabDriver` documents. You can maintain a relationship between them by using `ObjectId`'s . Store an array of `CabDriver._id` values in your `City` as `cab_drivers`, it would be much easier to query, validate and update them. Also the `cab_drivers` array inside a `City` document would grow much slower than in case of keeping the whole documents within the parent.

If you use `mongoose` you could then use: `city.populate('cab_drivers')` to load all related documents on application level.