# Is this the best mongodb schema for filtering a corpus of bag of words?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, schema, corpus

I have the following data schema within a mongo DB that contains a corpus of documents.

I have the 2 following collections:

- Dictionary collection that also embeds the list of doc ids where the word appears. This is done so you can easily filter your corpus of texts from a selection of words (frequency based, stop words, etc.)

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "executive",
    "key" : 1,
    "doc_ids" : {
        "108" : {},
        "109" : {},
        "110" : {},
        "111" : {},
        "112" : {},
        "115" : {},...
},...
```

- Document collection stored as a bag of word (each word is represented as a key:frequency tuple)

A document would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 108,
    "doc" : [ 
        [ 
            1, 
            1
        ], 
        [ 
            2, 
            1
        ], 
        [ 
            3, 
            1
        ],...
}
```

Originally, I started storing the list of doc ids within the dictionary collection as a table but as stated in some posts (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306815/mongodb-performance-with-growing-data-structure)), growing arrays are expensive.  It is the case for me as every time I process a new document I will add its id to existing words in my dictionary. 
This is why I replaced this array by nested empty sub documents.

Problem is that it doesn't improve the performance when updating existing words.

Is there another way I should structure my data to circumvent this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It's not just growing arrays that is expensive--it's any field that can grow unbounded, because what matters is the size of the document as a whole. So your `doc_ids` field would still be a problem. (If you're using WiredTiger though that may no longer be true--I couldn't find the answer easily when searching. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ZadQZ96Y9B0)

Comment: Also you might want to look into a text index for your application https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/